# how to fetch data with a condition using javascipt in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to load only specific number of rows where the condition satisfies.

However the following code fetches all the 25 rows and condition is not working.

Please someone help.

```
 loadCommentsFromServer = () => {
       fetch('/api/comments/', {
       method: 'GET',
       author: 'Dani'
   })
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.success) this.setState({ error: res.error });
        else this.setState({ data: res.data });
      });
  }
```

I am very new to javascript and reactjs, any help will save my weekend.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "condition is not working?" Is `res.success` falsy but `state` gets set to `error: res.error` ?

Comment: As far as the condition, have you tried accessing props on res object before converting res body to JSON ? Like this: loadCommentsFromServer = () => {
  fetch('/api/comments/', {
  method: 'GET',
  author: 'Dani'
})
 .then(res => {
   if(res.ok) {
     return res;
   } 
   throw new Error('Failure');
  })
 .then(data => data.json())
 .then(({ data }) => this.setSetState({ data }))
 .catch(err => this.setState({ err: err.message }))

Comment: In you code the res object is the WHOLE object derived from json reply, so, when you apply condition like res.success then you apply it to the whole response object, not to one of the array items that are supposed to be inside it. So, if that is correct, I would start going thought the items of the array. It depends of the exact structure of the result, but I guess it could be somehting like res.forEach ...

Comment: For fetching only x amount of rows, you just have to know how the API works to handle that, like `/api/comments?limit=25` or something

Comment: Hi Hero Qu , you are correct !!!

can you please share an example please ? i have 25 ROWS of Json DATA with 3 with 3 rows of author = 'Dani' when i use the above code it retrives all the 25ROWS and not 3 ROWS , Since am new to the javascript and nodejs want able to get any working examples so far . I am trying this for a week now .... any help please

Comment: Hi Hero Qu , you are correct !!!  am able to fix and thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t have access to the response in your second callback there.

```js
loadCommentsFromServer = () => {
  return fetch('/api/comments/', {
    method: 'GET',
    author: 'Dani'
  })
    .then((res) => {
      if (!res.success) this.setState({ error: res.error });
      else res.json().then(data => this.setState({ data }));
    });
}
```